# In the latest mui LoadingButton is missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

As per the material UI documentation,
https://next.material-ui.com/components/buttons/

you can
`import LoadingButton from '@material-ui/lab/LoadingButton';`
However, I don't see this folder anywhere in mui/lab and the import throws an error.

I ran `yarn add @material-ui/lab` already.

I also have `"@material-ui/core"` already.

Do I need to install something for 'next mui' as I see the documentation url is also different:
https://next.material-ui.com/

While most of components I have been using are here:
https://material-ui.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [getting-started/installation](https://next.material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/) you need `@next` to install upcoming version of core.

`yarn add @material-ui/core@next`

This also applies to `@material-ui/lab`

Comment: @T J, How to install it with npm. I tried `npm install @material-ui/core@next`. It shows error

Comment: try npm install @material-ui/core@next --legacy-peer-deps